# Looking for cd always on and mechanical sound- how can I stop this?

Tags: audio, compact-disc

I am having this strange thing with my cd-rom. Everytime I turn the pc on, or connect an external HD, or even launch winamp, it makes that annoying mechanical sound that kinda means it is looking for a cd.  I don't know what I did install but from that, my laptop always looks for a cd inside him even when there is no need.
I have a Samsung Chronos Series 7 NP700Z5C-S01IT.

Comment: Is the BIOS set to attempt to boot from a CD, and if that fails to boot from the HDD ?

Comment: I don't think so! Why does it even happen when winamp launches!?